# Question on Polymorphism unrelated classes with methods bearing the same name?

Tags: java, methods, polymorphism

Is it possible for methods in unrelated classes to exist, coincidentally bearing the same name/signature without having been inherited from another class or interface?

1. Could these also be described as “polymorphic” calls?
2. What are the downsides in attempting to use them polymorphically without inheriting from a parent class?

Comment: Can you give an example here on what you mean by polymorphic calls without inheritance in Java?

Comment: The whole reason for interfaces is so that otherwise-unrelated classes can have their own functions with the same name/signature, and those functions can be called.

Answer (score 1):

You're describing a situation called [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) - the analogy being "If it walks like a duck and it quacks like a duck, then it must be a duck", or to put it in OO terms - if it has the right method, we can call it.

Java, however, doesn't work like that.

At least not in any obvious way.

One was around this is with reflection. Assume you have two class, `A` and `B`, which both have a `doSomething()` method. You could get their `Class` objects in runtime, use them to get the relevant `method` object, and then call it:

```
public static void callSomething(Object o) throws Exception {
    Class<?> clazz = o.getClass();
    Method method = clazz.getMethod("doSomething");
    method.invoke(o);
}
```

This would work, but you're essentially throwing away all the benefits and protections Java affords you.

Unless you have a super-good reason to do this, I wouldn't go down that route.